# Can not find proper preset for ES6

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to build my react project with webpack and everywhere where it sees the following code

```
> 62 |   loadCommentsFromServer = () => {
     |                          ^
  63 |     $.ajax({
  64 |       url: this.props.url,
  65 |       dataType: 'json',
```

it throws an error.

```
> 30 |   showNav = () => {
     |           ^
  31 |     if ( this.state.isHidden ) {
  32 |       this.headerClass = 'main-header main-header--visible'
  33 |       this.setState({isHidden: false})
```

I'm using presets: ['react', 'es2015']
Which one do I need to build this code.

PS: There is no mistake in my code. It workes fine.

Comment: If it's a class method definition you need [transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin which is in the preset `stage-2`

Comment: @pawel, thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .babelrc you need to add the following presets.

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"]
}
```